# TypeError: passport.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am attempting to add the **passport service** to my app, but keep getting the following error, I believe I have installed all the dependencies. All searches for this error are futile.
Looking forward to your help:

Following is the error message I get in the terminal:

```
file:///home/sirbt/Desktop/UberAds/passport-config.js:37
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'loginEmailAddress'}, authenticateUser ))
             ^

TypeError: passport.use is not a function
    at initialize (file:///home/sirbt/Desktop/UberAds/passport-config.js:37:14)
    at file:///home/sirbt/Desktop/UberAds/server.js:32:28
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

Find below the contents of my `passport-config.js` file where the issue seems to originate from:

**./passport-config.js**

```
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";
import * as passport from "passport";
import pkg1 from 'bcrypt';
const {bcrypt } = pkg1;

export default function initialize( _passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById ) {
    const authenticateUser = async  (loginEmailAddress, loginPasswordSignIn, done) => {
        const user = getUserByEmail(loginEmailAddress)

        if(user == null) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'No user with that email' });
        }

        try {
            if( await bcrypt.compare(loginPasswordSignIn, user.password)){
                return done(null, user, { message:'Password incorrect' })
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message:'Password incorrect' })
            }

        } catch (e) {
            return done(e)            
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'loginEmailAddress'}, authenticateUser ))
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done( null, user.id ) )
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done( null, getUserById(id) ) 
    })

}
```

Following is my `server.js` app

**./server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
import Collection from 'mongodb';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import pkg3 from 'passport';
const { passport } = pkg3;

import pkg from 'express-flash';
const { flash } = pkg;

import pkg2 from 'express-session';
const { session } = pkg2;

import initialize from './passport-config.js';
const initializePassport = initialize();

initializePassport ( 
    passport, 
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
);

const bcryptt = bcrypt;
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const app  = express();

app.use(express.static ('public'));
app.use(express.json() );
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use( flash() );
app.use( session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}) );

app.use(passort.initialize());
app.use(passort.session());
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + 'public/images'));
app.use('/fonts', express.static(__dirname + 'public/fonts'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.route('/advertiserLogin')
    .get((req, res)=>{ 
        res.render('advertiserLogin', {name: "Sir BT!"});
    })

    .post( passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/advertiser',
        failureRedirect: '/advertiserLogin',
        failureFlash: true

    }) );


app.listen (7000)
```

And finally the contents of my `package.json` file

**./package.json**

```
{
  "name": "smartqueues",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.1",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

Desperately looking forward to your assistance!

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(passport)` *BEFORE* calling `.use()` in **passport-config.js**? just to make sure what have been imported. I'm thinking the passport lib may have some other stuff to import and you should import either the default export or an specific exported object. For example `import passport from "passport";` for the default export or `import { passport } from "passport";` to look for a specific object. I've never used this passport library but it seems logic if the object you're trying to use is exported as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the default export:

```
import passport from 'passport';
```